# Google Play Services - granting Oauth2 permission

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

Can you get the user to Authorize Oauth Permission(display the dialog) before a request is made?  I would like to ask my users to grant permissions when they first use the app.  The only way I know is to catch the UserRecoverableAuthException and launch the intent from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a call to http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) when your app first starts, which will either return a valid token if the user has already consented or throw UserRecoverableAuthException, in which case you should direct the user to the intent contained within.

Comment: Do you know how to repeat the UserRecoverableAuthIOException after you grant access? I need to test and debug my entire auth process